# why is the compiler treating character as an integer?

Tags: c, integer

I have a small snippet of code.
When I run this on my DevC++ gnu compiler it shows the following output:

```
 main ()
 {      char b = 'a';
        printf ("%d,", sizeof ('a'));
        printf ("%d", sizeof (b));
        getch ();
 }
```

> OUTPUT: 4,1

Why is `'a'` treated as an integer, whereas as `b` is treated as only a character constant?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Because character literals are of type `int` and not `char` in C.

So `sizeof 'a' == sizeof (int)`.

Note that in C++, a character literal is of type `char` and so `sizeof 'a' == sizeof (char)`.

Comment: I'm trying to find this in the standard. Do you have any idea where it is?

Comment: @chris (C99, 6.4 .4.4p10) "An integer character constant has type int."

Comment: sizeof (int)  is 4, sizeof (char) is 1.

Comment: @ouah, Ah, I was looking for "literal", not "constant". That'd look good in your answer.

Comment: @chris BTW, in the standard the word literal is used only for compound literals and string literals. But this is a standard CS term and even the C Committee uses it in the C Rationale or in Defect Reports for other constructs like for example for *character literals*.

Comment: @Vernon in this example this is true , but the standard does not gurantee that.

Answer (score 1):

That's just the way it is in C. That's just how the language was originally defined. As for why... Back then virtually everything in C was an `int`, unless there was a very good reason to make it something else. So, historically character constants in C have type `int`.

Note BTW, in C nomenclature `'a'` is called *constant*, not *literal*. C has string literals and no other literals.

Answer (score 0):

In C, a character literal has type int.

In C++, a character literal that contains only one character has type char, which is an integral type.

In both C and C++, a wide character literal has type wchar_t, and a multicharacter literal has type int.

Answer (score 0):

From IBM XL C/C++ documentation

> A character literal contains a sequence of characters or escape
>   sequences enclosed in single quotation mark symbols, for example 'c'.
>   A character literal may be prefixed with the letter L, for example
>   L'c'. A character literal without the L prefix is an ordinary
>   character literal or a narrow character literal. A character literal
>   with the L prefix is a wide character literal. An ordinary character
>   literal that contains more than one character or escape sequence
>   (excluding single quotes ('), backslashes () or new-line characters)
>   is a multicharacter literal.
>
> Character literals have the following form:

```
             .---------------------.
             V                     |
>>-+---+--'----+-character-------+-+--'------------------------><
   '-L-'       '-escape_sequence-'
```

> At least one character or escape sequence must appear in the character
>   literal. The characters can be from the source program character set,
>   excluding the single quotation mark, backslash and new-line symbols. A
>   character literal must appear on a single logical source line.
>
> C A character literal has type int